# I want to add two tables one after one in a section using latex. But, my second table is going to another section. What to do?

Tags: latex

In my 2nd section I want to add two table. One table is in the right position, but the second table went to the next section. it was supposed to be in the previous section. How can I bring the second table in the right section?

Here is the code I used:

```
% table 3 begins
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{}
    \label{my-label}
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}
        \hline
        \textbf{Properties} & \textbf{Model 1} & \textbf{Model 2} & \textbf{Model 3} \\ \hline
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Training\\ Window width\end{tabular} & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Training\\ window step\end{tabular} & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Test\\ window width\end{tabular} & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
        Horizon & 5 & 10 & 15 \\
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Cumulative\\ training\end{tabular} & No & No & No \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\\


% table 4 begins
\begin{table}[!t]
    \centering
    \caption{}
    \label{my-label}
    \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
        \hline
        \textbf{Date} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Actual Price\\ (USD)\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Predicted Price}} \\ \hline
        \textbf{} & \textbf{} & \textbf{Model 1} & \textbf{Model 1} & \textbf{Model 1} \\
        13-01-15 & 89.30 & 89.44 & 87.90 & 91.71 \\
        07-11-14 & 78.76 & 77.63 & 77.72 & 78.08 \\
        29-07-14 & 75.44 & 75.00 & 76.43 & 77.59 \\
        04-06-14 & 77.12 & 76.26 & 76.96 & 77.53 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: please give feedback as to whether any of the answers below solved your question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Latex, which has its own site now.

Answer (score 4):

It's not so much that LaTeX put the second table in the next *section*, but it put it on the next *page* that had room.  LaTeX has a slightly intricate algorithm for working out how best to relocate tables and figures, but unfortunately its decisions can be rather ... unpredictable.

One solution is to accept that this is OK, and perhaps give the reader a clue by saying `see table~\ref{my-label} on page~\pageref{my-label}`, which helps the reader find the table.  The `varioref` package can do this in a smarter way.  I think, myself, that this is the best solution.

Another is to adjust the maximum fraction of a page that LaTeX will permit to have tables.  A command like `\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.75}` will permit up to three quarters of the page to be floats – so only a quarter of the page text – before spilling on to a new page.  This can quickly look ugly if the fraction is too large, however.

This is a very common problem, and searching online for ‘controlling latex floats’, or similar, should uncover lots of help.  There should also be help on this topic elsewhere on Stackoverflow, or on the [companion TeX site](https://tex.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Norman Gray:s answer, I might also add that there are several different methods to force your floats (tables/figures and so on) to stay within "their" sections.

One method would be to use the `placeins` package, as described [in its documentation](http://ctan.mirrorcatalogs.com/macros/latex/contrib/placeins/placeins-doc.pdf). From the documentation:

> **Placeins.sty** keeps floats ‘in their place’, preventing them from
>   floating past a “`\FloatBarrier`” command into another section. To use
>   it, declare “`\usepackage{placeins}`” and insert “`\FloatBarrier`” at
>   places that floats should not move past, perhaps at every
>   “`\section`”.
>
> ...
>
> If you specify “`\usepackage[section]{placeins}`”, then the “`\section`” command will be redefined with “`\FloatBarrier`” inserted at the beginning.

So in your case, try adding

```
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
```

in your document header.